# upload artifact in GitHub Action

Tags: github, github-actions

How do I update the following code so that artifact contains a folder named 'Scripts' and all the files are copied to 'Scripts' folder?

```
 - name: copy scripts
      run: Copy 'Scripts/' '${{ github.workspace }}/Scripts'
      shell: powershell

- name: publish artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
      with:
        path: ${{ github.workspace }}/Scripts
        name: ${{ github.run_number }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
 - name: Create Artifact Folder
   run: New-Item -Path '${{ github.workspace }}' -Name "Artifacts" -ItemType "directory"
   shell: powershell
 - name: Copy Scripts
   run: Copy 'Scripts/' '${{ github.workspace }}/Artifacts/Scripts'
   shell: powershell
 - name: Publish Artifact
   uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
   with:
     path: ${{ github.workspace }}/Artifacts
     name: ${{ github.run_number }}
```

Just create a folder between your artifact and your desired files

Comment: Thank you! Tried this and it is showing error: No files were found with the provided path: D:\a\gmm-build\gmm-build/Artifacts. No artifacts will be uploaded.

Comment: Did the other steps work? I am not sure if that was the correct one for creating a folder (and I also wrote Atrifacts instead of `Artifacts)`

Comment: The build succeeded. However I don't see Artifacts folder. I fixed the typo but still not working.

Comment: I tried updating the the step to: run: | mkdir -p ${{ github.workspace }}/Artifacts and used your steps to copy and publish. But that gives error: Warning: No files were found with the provided path: D:\a\gmm-build\gmm-build/Artifacts. No artifacts will be uploaded.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?